# replace outlier values of a time series with other values in the time series

Tags: r, dplyr, outliers

I have a time series and I want to replace outliers with other (not outliers) values randomly.
The time series is as follows:

```
date           Category      Value1
2018-09-10       A            .4
2018-09-10       B            .6
2018-09-10       A             4
2018-09-10       C            .2
2018-09-10       D             7
```

Then I have tried to determine the outlier as following:

```
qn = quantile(df1$value1, c(0.05, 0.85), na.rm = TRUE)
df6 = within(df1, { value = ifelse(df1$value1 < qn[1], qn[1], df1$value1)
value = ifelse(df1$value1  > qn[2], qn[2], df1$value1 )})
```

Then I want to replace the outlier values with some values from column `value1` which are not outlier.

Comment: Sure I put a data frame I did not know sorry about that

Comment: Why would you want that? Outliers are data too.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace outlier values randomly one way would be

```
#Find out indices which are outliers
inds <- df1$Value1 > qn[2] | df1$Value1 < qn[1]

#Replace those outliers by randomly selecting non-outliers  
df1$Value1[inds] <- sample(df1$Value1[!inds], sum(inds))

df1
#       date  Category Value1
#1 2018-09-10        A    0.4
#2 2018-09-10        B    0.6
#3 2018-09-10        A    4.0
#4 2018-09-10        C    4.0
#5 2018-09-10        D    0.6
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "date           Category      Value1
                          2018-09-10       A            .4
                          2018-09-10       B            .6
                          2018-09-10       A             4
                          2018-09-10       C            .2
                          2018-09-10       D             7", header =T)

qn <- quantile(df1$Value1, c(0.05, 0.85), na.rm = TRUE)
```